# Can I work around the breaking change in how filenames are computed when moving from Liquibase 3 to 4?

Tags: liquibase

We have had the following file layout for the Liquibase changelogs since 2015:

```
src/main/resources/database/db.changelog-master.xml
src/main/resources/database/changelogs
src/main/resources/database/changelogs/20180823-2054-attachments-table.xml
```

We pass `database/db.changelog-master.xml` to Liquibase and it goes from there.

In version 3 this setup would result in the filename of a ChangeLog being `changelogs/20180823-2054-attachments-table.xml`, whereas in version 4 this results in the filename `database/changelogs/20180823-2054-attachments-table.xml` (notice the extra `database/` prefix). This broke the migrations, as it compares the filenames of what is in the database with the ones in the app, and now all the old ones seem like they do not exist.

I found two workarounds:

- set [logicalFilePath](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/logicalfilepath.html) for every script. Nothing then needs to change location, but all files need touching now and forever.
- move all files up one level, dropping the `database` directory. This is the least invasive

Still, I would have liked if there was a way of handling this without touching files or moving them around. I think I tracked this down to [this PR](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1225) that was part of the initial Liquibase version 4 release, which changes related code, but I cannot see any way of making filenames relative to some folder.